# Android: Checking if google settings location is enabled

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

I'm working on an app that uses google play services. On Some phones, the client returns null for location. This happens because the locaiton option is not enabled on google setting as in the pic attached.

How to programatically check if google settings location is enabled in an android app ?

http://www.cnet.com/how-to/explaining-the-google-settings-icon-on-your-android-device/

Comment: use `LocationManager` to check the different providers

Comment: It's possible to check if google play services itself is available. Follow instructions here:
https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html It's possible getLastLocation() will return null even if Google Play Services Location Services are enabled. For instance, right after re-enabling them. However you can then take your user to the Google Play Services Location Settings by using [this Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26959837).

Answer (score 1):

I thought this is the best solution.

You can check by following code :

```
    /**
     * This is used to check whether location is enabled or not.
     * @param mContext
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isDeviceLocationEnabled(Context mContext) {
        int locMode = 0;
        String locProviders;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
            try {
                locMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(mContext.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
            } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
            return locMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF;
        }else{
            locProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
            return !TextUtils.isEmpty(locProviders);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be one change, where you check `TextUtils.isEmpty(locationProviders)`. It is never empty. Where there is no provider (location settings are disabled) it has value `"null"`. Yes I mean value `"null"`, not `null`.